# Combining / nesting subscription to multiple collections in Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, rxjs, angularfire

I'm looking for a way to fetch data from multiple collections in a subscription.

I have two collections: `inspection_processes` and `inspections`. Each `inspection` belongs to exact one `inspection_process`. Each `inspection` contains data (foreign keys) from another collection called `devices`.

My goal is to get a list of all `inspection_processes` and fetch their respective `inspections` and the `devices` specified in each `inspection`.

Here's the data from Firestore (displayed JSON-like for better readability:

```
inspection_processes = [{
  id: 'AAA',
  process_name: 'P-001'
}]

inspections = [{
  inspection_id: 'BBB',
  inspection_process_id: 'AAA',
  device_id: 'CCC'
}]

devices = [{
  device_id: 'DDD',
  device_name: 'Computer'
}]
```

**My current (simplified) approach:**

```
fetchInspectionProcesses() {

  let inspecion_processes_data = [];

  // Get inspection processes
  this.getInspectionProcesses().subscribe(inspecion_processes => {

    for (let inspection_process of inspecion_processes) {

      // Get inspections of inspection process
      this.getInspectionsByProcessId(inspection_process['id']).subscribe(inspections => {

        for (let inspection of inspections) {

          // Get device info
          this.getDeviceById(inspection['device_id']).subscribe(device => {
          
            // ... push data to inspecion_processes_data array
          })
        }
      })
    }
  })
}
```

I know that this approach isn't recommended since it leads to different problems (duplicate output in the UI, memory leaks, ...).

I did my best trying to solve it by using RxJS (e.g. by piping) but I didn't manage to use the right operators. The problem is not limited to having two or three collections to combine, I'm looking for a general approach on how to do this.
Working with duplicate data (e.g. putting the device's name in the `inspections` document isn't an option since my example is just simplified, there are many nestings I have to deal with.

EDIT: Screenshot of the Firebase Console
[image]

Can anyone help, please? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you add a screenshot from Firebase Console as well?

Comment: @Dharmaraj added a screenshot from Firebase.

Answer (score 0):

What you're talking about is basically a join in firestore. You should really duplicate your data so you don't have to do this.  I wrote some functions to do this in my package

https://github.com/jdgamble555/adv-firestore-functions#Aggregation

But you could also do SQL like joins (but you will incur more reads):

https://fireship.io/lessons/firestore-joins-similar-to-sql/

J

Answer (score 0):

This is how you might remove your nested subscriptions

```ts
fetchInspectionProcesses() {

  let inspecion_processes_data = [];

  this.getInspectionProcesses().pipe(
    map(inspecion_processes => inspecion_processes.map(
      inspection_process => this.getInspectionsByProcessId(inspection_process['id'])
    )),
    mergeMap(processes => merge(...processes)),
    map(inspections => inspections.map(
      inspection => this.getDeviceById(inspection['device_id'])
    )),
    mergeMap(devices => merge(...devices)),
    toArray()
  ).subscribe(deviceArray => {
    // ... This is your inspecion_processes_data array
  });

}
```

Or, a little bit more compactly by combining map and mergeMap together:

```ts
fetchInspectionProcesses() {

  let inspecion_processes_data = [];

  this.getInspectionProcesses().pipe(
    mergeMap(inspecion_processes => merge(...inspecion_processes.map(
      inspection_process => this.getInspectionsByProcessId(inspection_process['id'])
    ))),
    mergeMap(inspections => merge(...inspections.map(
      inspection => this.getDeviceById(inspection['device_id'])
    ))),
    toArray()
  ).subscribe(deviceArray => {
    // ... Do something with deviceArray
  });

}
```